# How to get the total rows for pagination within the least amount of processing time.

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I get the total rows for pagination within the least amount of processing time?

My select SQL in products list is too complex for showing the total pages in pagination. I have to query the SQL with no limit parameter which takes too much time to process. Is there a better way to get the total records?

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.products_model,
    p.products_image,
    pd.products_name,
    p.products_quantity,
    p.products_id,
    p.products_type,
    p.master_categories_id,
    p.manufacturers_id,
    p.products_price,
    products_price_market,
    p.products_tax_class_id,
    pd.products_description,

IF (pbs.products_id, 1, 0) pdsid,

IF (
    s. STATUS = 1,
    s.specials_new_products_price,
    NULL
) AS specials_new_products_price,

IF (
    s. STATUS = 1,
    s.specials_new_products_price,
    p.products_price
) AS final_price,
 p.products_sort_order,
 p.product_is_call,
 p.product_is_always_free_shipping,
 p.products_qty_box_status,
 p.products_recommend,
 p.products_in_stock
FROM
    jy_products_description pd,
    jy_products p
LEFT JOIN jy_products_best_selling pbs ON p.products_id = pbs.products_id
AND pbs.category_id = 77,
 jy_products_to_categories p2c
LEFT JOIN jy_specials s ON p2c.products_id = s.products_id
AND s. STATUS = 1,
 jy_products_attributes pa0
WHERE
    p.products_status = 1
AND p.products_quantity > 0
AND p.products_id = p2c.products_id
AND pd.products_id = p2c.products_id
AND p.products_id = pa0.products_id
AND pd.language_id = 1
AND p2c.categories_id = 77
ORDER BY
    pdsid DESC,
    pbs.sort_by ASC,
    p.products_ordered
```

[image]

Comment: how long is to long? what's indexed?

Comment: You don't need to order the results to get total rows. I think, if you remove, order by clause then response will be much faster for count(*). Also, make sure proper indexes are in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
STATUS = 1 AND
catagory = 100
HAVING
quantity > 0
ORDER BY
sort ASC
```

This will gain the full Query using PDO you can just COUNT the Amount you have in Total. Store that in the Session, and then finally use this.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
STATUS = 1 AND
catagory = 100
HAVING
quantity > 0
ORDER BY
sort ASC
LIMIT #, #
```

Combined with your Total Count, you can Divide the Count by the # Of Items your Showing on the Page. With that you can then use that to determine the number of pages. Round up of course. then simply use go about the amount limit, on each paganation that you stored in the session on your first run, this way you dont kill your calls constantly.